# How to transfer html object to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

As HTML can be parsed by `jsdom` in `nodejs`, and rendering HTML takes much workload. Can we render it on server side and transfer HTML object to client?

In this way, client side only need to append to document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you what universal app check this [isomorphic](http://isomorphic.net/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact it is not the same. I only want to transfer the binary object to browser. Browser do not need to render it. Browser only need to append to document node.

Comment: Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can use `innerHTML` to do this.

Comment: InnerHTML will need to render the tag----Parse the html, analysis the semantic, create DOM object. If transfer DOM object directly, do not need to parse, analysis.